# Indexing with two digits

Tags: indexing, double, digits

I have written the following code in my HTML form:

```
<select name="createdDay"><?php for ($i=1; $i <= 31 ; $i++) 
{echo '<option>' . $i . '</option>';} ?>
```

The index only goes up in single digits to 10 obviously, is there a way that I can use two digits please? Example 01, 02, 03, 04......

I have tried pre-fixing a 0 or have i=01 but to no avail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf), which allows you to specify formatting/padding chars, like

```
$formatted = sprintf('%02d', $i); // 1 -> 01, 10 -> 10
```